# Implementing a custom serializer in Serde (Rust), only for optional values

Tags: rust, serialization, serde

I'm working on a Tauri app (Rust backend) and the app settings are stored in a JSON file. I'm loading these into the program with `serde` and `serde_json`. The `Settings` struct looks like this (minimal example):

```
pub struct Settings {
  pub languages: Option<Vec<String>>;
  pub show_version_in_title_bar: Option<bool>;
  pub theme: Option<String>;
}
```

The idea is that all fields in the settings file are optional, and are treated in Rust as `None`. (What should happen in the `None` case can be implemented elsewhere in the program.)

Now, the default behaviour when serialising this struct into JSON is to convert `None` into `null`. I want `None` fields in the struct to not be included in the final output. Looking for answers online, I found two possible approaches: annotating every field with `#[serde(skip_serialization_if = "Option::is_none")]` or implementing your own `Serializer`. Since the settings file might get quite large, I don't find the former approach optimal.

My question now is: is there a way to implement a serializer, redefining only the behaviour for `None` (the `serialize_none` method on `Serializer`) without having to implement all the other methods, for which the default behaviour is fine?